# How to deal with user permissions for admin/users when adding new permissions?

Tags: mysql, database, data-structures, permissions

I am creating a website where all users have different types of permissions.

I am not doing role based permissions.

Users can join different groups and get different permissions for each group.

The part I am struggling with here is how to deal with the admin(group creator) permissions.

The admins permissions are a little different from regular users because admins always have access to every permission even when new permissions are added.

While users have to be given the permission by an admin., an admin can give all of their permissions to a user except editing the admins permissions.

I imagine I can have a table where there are `UsersId`, `PermissionId`, `Type(Admin/User)`, `GroupID`.

There will only be 1 admin per group. But the part that seems asinine to me is if we (the application) were to add another permission capability. We would have to query every `UserID` with `type = Admin`, and insert a record for that permission. That seems horribly inefficient. Is there a better way I can do this?

Comment: Have a special PermissionId that means "all" to your system. Alternatively, ignore the PermissionId in the case that the Type is Admin. Alternatively, have a special PermissionId that means "admin" and remove the Type field entirely.

Comment: What might another permission capability be? (Although I think I can see why role-based permissions are popular)

Comment: Yes roles are a good idea, but this application isnt going to have roles. It is mainly going to allow each user of the group to have access to features in the group, set by the admin, or other appointed users. Its really just `Super admin` and `users`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `AdminUserId` column on your `Group` table.

Comment: ok, i thought about that. but then how do I handle permissions when a `user/admin` logs in and goes to the group? Do I query the `Group` table for the `AdminUserId` compare it to the `UserId` `If AdminUserId !== UserId` then Query `UserPermissions` table? Or can this all be done in one query? I was trying to avoid doing 2 queries. Im not sure, what to do

Comment: You can keep `isGroupAdmin` value in the user session when user logs in. You can also keep `userPermissions` value in the user session if its frequently used.

Comment: ok, i think I will do that. if there are many permissions, should I store them in an array and check to see if the user permission is in the array?